# Why are my margins still collapsing?

Tags: css, margin

My code in this ["Fiddle"](http://jsfiddle.net/gKeEF/1/) shows that I have adjacent elements which vertical margins are collapsing on one another.  I understand that due to the nature of vertical margins in css, the largest of the two is chosen, In my case the p tag.

What I am having trouble with is trying to break the margins by using a 1px border or 1px padding.  I've seen it work with other workarounds such as `position:absolute` or `float` method.  I am not understanding why using 1px border or padding is not working properly to give me 15px of space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a some techniques to prevent collapsing of the margins. You said about two of them: absolute position and float. In addition you can use `display: inline-block` for your `p` tags. In [this guide](http://www.complexspiral.com/publications/uncollapsing-margins/) I found the solution with borders and paddings only for nested elements. And, of course, you can use really big borders instead of margins :)

Comment: So you saying that the padding is only for nested elements correct?

Comment: @BrandonDorsey I've tried to get it to work in some variations. I think 1px padding doesn't work in your situation. But maybe somebody know the true technique.

Comment: displaying the div as an inline-block helps achieve the 20px of marginal spacing.  And your right the 1px border does not work in this situation.  It only works when an element is nested.

Comment: To clarify: the reason padding blocks margin collapse within nesting elements is because the padding appears between the outer margin and the inner margin. It does not prevent margins from collapsing between two adjacent elements.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to use a border or background on either the p or div?  If not, use a padding in one or both of your styles.  Padding does not collapse like margins do.

```
p {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
div {
    padding: 1px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}​
```

If you do include a border or background, using padding might not give the look you're going for because borders are outside of the padding and backgrounds include the padding area.

Comment: Eventually I will run into a situation where I have to use a bg, and I wish to know how to fix this issue by using a border or padding.

Comment: Well, it's only a problem if you need a border or background on both of the elements.  If it's only the div, for example, use margin on the div and padding on the p.

Comment: There are other methods as well.  You can use floats and clears, overflows, or positioning.  These times of solutions may or may not work, depending on your page layout.  There is a nice write-up here: http://www.seifi.org/css/understanding-taming-collapsing-margins-in-css.html about it.

Answer (score -1):

To make them displayed next to each other change the following:

```
p {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display:inline;
}

div {
    padding: 1px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    display:inline;
}​
```

Comment: the OP doesn't want to display them next to each other